# getting object from HQL query

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a project involving struts2 and hibernate.Actually I want to execute the select query below and store the values into a object of type Users.i tried using tostring(),querystring() methods all return only the query asa  string.I tried googling it said "HQL returns result in the form of objects" but i cant get the members of the class using query.how to get it please help thanks in advance

```
Query query=session.createQuery(" from Users where userid=:temp");
query.setParameter("temp", "kumar");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<User> users = query.list();
```

looks like it should work (assuming your tables and entities are set up). You could also use a [criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

Comment: thanks alot NimChimpsky i have used it now but for that i have to iterate the list and copy the all members to object.Is there any way where i can straight away retieve the values into my object without creating list?

Comment: hibernate populates the lsit with all the values, thats the point.